# How to group 2 objects into one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  var note = {
      text: "test 1",
      badges: ["testing", "111"],
    };
    var note2 = {
      text: "test 2",
      badges: ["testing", "222"],
    };

    var newData = {...note, ...note2}

    console.log("newData :", newData);
```

The output is not what im looking for, it overwrites it and only shows the last obj. Im expecting like having both objects on a single one or should I use an array for that instead?

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: You cannot have same keys in a single object. If there are then the last one overrides the earlier ones. So, here in this case you have `text` in `note` and `note2` as well and when you do this `{...note, ...note2}`, `note2`'s `text` overrides the easier `note.text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread syntax `...note` puts the keys of note into newData, so it looks exactly like note at that point. Then `...note2` overwrites those values with the contents of note2. So you can do:

```
var newData = {note, note2};
```

which gives you two objects with keys `note` and `note2` on newData:

```
{ 
   note: {
      text: "test 1",
      badges: ["testing", "111"],
   },
   note2: {
      text: "test 2",
      badges: ["testing", "222"],
   },
}
```

Or you can just push the objects into an array of course.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to use your grouping there are really 2 main options.

**Single object**

Each object will have its own unique key.

```js
const note = {
  text: "test 1",
  badges: ["testing", "111"],
};
const note2 = {
  text: "test 2",
  badges: ["testing", "222"],
};

const newData = {
  note,
  note2
}

console.log("newData :", newData);
```

**Array**

Iterate through the item with ease.

```js
const note = {
  text: "test 1",
  badges: ["testing", "111"],
};
const note2 = {
  text: "test 2",
  badges: ["testing", "222"],
};

const newData = [note, note2]

console.log("newData :", newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this..

```
var note = {
  text: "test 1",
  badges: ["testing", "111"],
};
var note2 = {
  text: "test 2",
  badges: ["testing", "222"],
};

var newData = [note, note2]

console.log("newData :", newData);
```

Using this **var newData = {...note, ...note2}** is typically expanding object in object and since property name is same and object is treated as key value pair, you are getting last object as result.